# Need to refresh page to see results in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I have an if statement that checks whether the user is logged in or not to display different elements in the navigational bar (Log in if not a user and Log Out if a user).

Below is the if-statement, located in Master.master (Master page, obviously)

```
            <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["email"] != null)
               { %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form method="post" runat="server" role="form">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    <li><a id="btnLogOut" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" onserverclick="LogOutUser">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
            <% }
               else
               { %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <form id="loginform" method="post" runat="server" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="login-controls input-group col-xs-12">
                                <a id="btnLogIn" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" onserverclick="LogInUser" class="btn btn-default col-xs-4">Login</a>
                                <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7 checkbox-inline">
                                    <label class="navbar-text">
                                        <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" />
                                        Remember me

                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="loginMessageArea" class="alert alert-danger" runat="server">
                            </div>
                            <div class="navbar-text" id="no-account">
                                Don't have an account?
                                <a href="./Register.aspx">Register here!</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <% } %>
```

When clicking the log out button, this is the event fired.

```
public void LogOutUser(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if the user clicks log out, the page will refresh, and nothing will happen. If I refresh the page, though, I see the change. How can I change it so that I get the results without another page refresh?

**Edit:** Pasted where the if statement is.

Comment: Where (in what part of your application) is this `if` statement declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is going on here. User clicks the log out button, and the postback occurs. The `if` statement you have is executed during the initialization phase, and at that moment of time user is not logged out yet. Then the event handling happens, and user is logged out by the code you have in the `LogOutUser` handler. Now the user is logged out indeed, but the `if` in markup is already executed and won't be executed again during this page loading! So nothing changes on the page.

However when you refresh the page user is already logged outwhen initialization happens, so `if` statement is evaluated as you expect it to.

To fix this you can, instead of simple `if`, wrap the markup in `ContentPlaceHolder` and setup its visibility on `PreRender` whe authentication status is known for sure:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    ...
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["email"] != null)
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still a beginner at ASP, so your elaboration helps me better understand for future references.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest to put breakpoint on LogOutUser and Page_PreRender, in order to determine calling order.

Could be linked to page lifecycle management

See:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667308/ASP-NET-Page-Life-Cycle-Events

Maurizio

Answer (score 0):

Solved it temporarily by adding `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`

My code turned out like so:

```
protected void LogOutUser(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```